# Central JS Timer

Tags: javascript

Looking at [Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja](http://www.manning.com/resig/), I took this code for a "Central Timer":

```
var timers = {

    timerID: 0,
    timers: [],

    add: function(fn) { 
        this.timers.push(fn);
    },

    start: function() {
        if(this.timerID) return;
        (function runNext() {
            if(timers.timers.length > 0) {
               for (var i = 0; i < timers.length; i++) {
                 if(timers.timers[i]() === false) {
                   timers.timers.splice(i,1);
                   i--;
                 }
              } 
    console.log("setting timeout.");
    timers.timerID = setTimeout(runNext, 0);
       }
     })();
    },

    stop: function() {
        clearTimeout(this.timerID);
        this.timerID = 0;
    }
};
```

Then, test it out.

```
 var box = document.getElementById("box"), x = 0, y = 20;
    timers.add(function() {
        box.style.left = x + "px";
        log.console("x:", x);
        if(++x > 50) return false;
    });

    timers.add(function() { 
        box.style.top = y + "px";
        y += 2;
        log.console("y:", y);
        if (++y > 120) return false;
    });

    console.log("starting timer.");
```

But, looking at my console, I see `setting timeout` scrolling endlessly without any increment to `x` or `y`.

What's going on here?

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VCLNy/1/)

**EDIT** Page # - 210/394.

Note - it's possible I made a copy/paste mistake - not blaming.

Comment: Could you please link to the actual page you copied the code from? Perhaps that would make things a bit clearer.

Comment: sure. I just added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`timers.length` is `undefined` in the `for` loop in `runNext`, so the code does not actually iterate over the intended array. Either you transcribed it incorrectly or the code in the book has a bug. Regardless, this is the correct loop:

```
//                        ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
for (var i = 0; i < timers.timers.length; i++) {
  if(timers.timers[i]() === false) {
    timers.timers.splice(i,1);
    i--;
  }
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/HN8CX/)**

Comment: ah - my mistake. the book is **correct**. I copied it incorrectly. Thanks.

Comment: should I delete this question since I made a mistake copying it?